# Anylogic Model stopped working after updating from 8.8.1 to 8.8.2

Tags: anylogic

Tested that the model is working in 8.8.1 but not 8.8.2

The Error Message is as followed:

```
Error during model creation:
class [Lcom.anylogic.engine.presentation.ModelElementDescriptorUtils; cannot be cast to class [Lcom.anylogic.engine.presentation.ModelElementDescriptor; ([Lcom.anylogic.engine.presentation.ModelElementDescriptorUtils; and [Lcom.anylogic.engine.presentation.ModelElementDescriptor; are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Lcom.anylogic.engine.presentation.ModelElementDescriptorUtils; cannot be cast to class [Lcom.anylogic.engine.presentation.ModelElementDescriptor; ([Lcom.anylogic.engine.presentation.ModelElementDescriptorUtils; and [Lcom.anylogic.engine.presentation.ModelElementDescriptor; are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.anylogic.libraries.pypeline.PyCommunicator.doCreate(PyCommunicator.java:2165)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.createAsEmbedded(Unknown Source)
    at combined.Main.doCreate(Main.java:6779)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.createAsEmbedded(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.f$f.run(Unknown Source)
Error during drawing animation frame:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.RackSystem.reserved(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.RackSystem.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.RackSystem$4.updateDynamicProperties(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.Shape.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeGroup.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeGroup.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeGroup.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeEmbeddedObjectIcon.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeGroup.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Presentable.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Presentable.updateShapeDynamicProperties(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.SVGFrameProducer.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost$1.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost$1.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.SVGFrameCollector.b(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Is there any idea where the error is from the message?

Thank you

Comment: impossible to say with this info

Comment: I've been having the same issue. So far I've gotten this error when using the following (external) AnyLogic libraries: Material Design UI - 1.4.6, Pathmind, and Pypeline. If anyone knows a workaround, it would be extremely helpful! Simply placing a block from one of these libraries causes this error to occur on model startup.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by significant changes in internal code after moving to AnyLogic 8.8.2. This will disappear once you update Pypeline library you are using in the project as it has been updated for resolving the issue.